# Find closest point on path forwards

Tags: ios, location

Given a path say 1000 meters long from start to goal consisting of a finite number of `CLLocation` points (guesstimate around 100). Assuming the user is somewhere on the path and a `CLLocation` coming from iOS location services, what would be the best way to calculate the nearest point forwards along the route?

Finding the nearest point is easy enough using `-[CLLocation distanceFromLocation:]`, but as the user passes a point and moves towards the next, the previous point will still be the nearest until he passes the midway between the previous and next point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep a array consisting of the sorted (start to the end of the path) CLLocation points (hypothetical 100) and evaluate only those poins to find the nearest one that will be visited. To find a visited point you keep the starting position and mesure the distance from the start to the current location of the user(d1). If d1 > distance from start to the next point in the sorted array and the current location is nearby (10 - 100 m) the next point in sorted array then remove the point else user did not visit / passed by that location so you keep it in the sorted array.

Comment: I already have an array of all the path points, but how can I know if the user visits or passes one? Path points and actual user locations will at best be close, never exact matches.

Comment: Actually, that was the implementation I already had (just reversed, looking forwards instead) but with a bug in it. Seems to work just fine now. Thanks anyway :)